# Re-write $1 \cdot x$ to $x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given the following bi-directional re-write rules (where $1$ is a constant, $^{-1}$ is a unary operator, $\cdot$ is a binary operator, and $x,y,z$ are arbitrary terms):

$$\begin{align*}
x \cdot 1 &= x \\
x \cdot (y \cdot z) &= (x\cdot y) \cdot z \\
x \cdot x^{-1} &= 1
\end{align*}$$

we're asked to prove that $1 \cdot x = x$ (ie, there is a chain $t_0 \to t_1 \to t_3 \to \cdots \to t_n$ with $t_0 = 1\cdot x$, $t_n = x$, and $t_i \to t_{i+1}$ meaning one of the 3 equations above re-writes $t_i$ to $t_{i+1}$ (in either direction)).

After staring at this for a while I'm beginning to doubt whether or not this is possible... can anyone a) confirm this is indeed possible and b) potentially nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show that inverses are unique and then show that the inverse of $x^{-1}$ is both $x$ and $1 \cdot x$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, observe that:
\begin{align*}
1 \cdot x &= (x \cdot x^{-1}) \cdot x \\
&= x \cdot \left(x^{-1} \cdot x\right) \\
&= x \cdot \left((x^{-1} \cdot x) \cdot 1\right) \\
&= x \cdot \left((x^{-1} \cdot x) \cdot (x^{-1} \cdot (x^{-1})^{-1}) \right) \\
&= x \cdot \left(((x^{-1} \cdot x) \cdot x^{-1}) \cdot (x^{-1})^{-1} \right) \\
&= x \cdot \left((x^{-1} \cdot (x \cdot x^{-1})) \cdot (x^{-1})^{-1} \right) \\
&= x \cdot \left((x^{-1} \cdot 1) \cdot (x^{-1})^{-1} \right) \\
&= x \cdot \left(x^{-1}\cdot (x^{-1})^{-1} \right) \\
&= x \cdot  1 \\
&= x \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Wow -- I feel like I would not have managed that on my own.... I guess I was expecting something less complicated given how simple the theorem seemed.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a "cool" way to do it (well, at least, I think it's "cool").  If we input the assumptions into the automated theorem prover [Prover9](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/):

```
formulas(assumptions).
  x*1=x.
  x*(y*z)=(x*y)*z.
  x*x'=1.
end_of_list.

formulas(goals).
  1*x=x.
end_of_list.
```

It will return a proof:

```
============================== PROOF =================================

% Proof 1 at 0.01 (+ 0.00) seconds.
% Length of proof is 12.
% Level of proof is 6.
% Maximum clause weight is 11.
% Given clauses 8.

1 1 * x = x # label(non_clause) # label(goal).  [goal].
2 x * 1 = x.  [assumption].
3 x * (y * z) = (x * y) * z.  [assumption].
4 (x * y) * z = x * (y * z).  [copy(3),flip(a)].
5 x * x' = 1.  [assumption].
6 1 * c1 != c1.  [deny(1)].
7 x * (1 * y) = x * y.  [para(2(a,1),4(a,1,1)),flip(a)].
8 x * (x' * y) = 1 * y.  [para(5(a,1),4(a,1,1)),flip(a)].
13 1 * x'' = x.  [para(5(a,1),8(a,1,2)),rewrite([2(2)]),flip(a)].
15 x * y'' = x * y.  [para(13(a,1),4(a,2,2)),rewrite([2(2)])].
16 1 * x = x.  [para(13(a,1),7(a,2)),rewrite([15(5),7(4)])].
17 $F.  [resolve(16,a,6,a)].

============================== end of proof ==========================
```

Comment: Did Prover9 do a "proof by contradiction" by assuming the negation of what it was trying to prove (6) and just proving what it wanted directly (16) and then observing "hey, what we wanted contradicts its own negation" (17)? That's a little silly, but I suppose I can't beat a time of .01 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Another method of proof would be:

Using the fact that $x = (x^{-1})^{-1}$, then $x^{-1} \cdot x = 1$ from axiom 3.

\begin{align*}
&1 \cdot 1 = 1 \\
&1 \cdot (x \cdot x^{-1}) = 1 \\
&(1 \cdot x) \cdot x^{-1} = x \cdot x^{-1} \\
&((1 \cdot x) \cdot x^{-1}) \cdot x = (x \cdot x^{-1}) \cdot x \\
&(1 \cdot x) \cdot (x^{-1} \cdot x) = x \cdot (x^{-1} \cdot x) \\
&(1 \cdot x) \cdot 1 = x \cdot 1 \\
&1 \cdot x = x \\
\end{align*}

Comment: A large chunk of Adriano's proof (and the Prover9 proof) amounts to showing that $(x^{-1})^{-1}=x$.  If we can assume this: $$1x=(xx^{-1})x=x(x^{-1}x)=x(x^{-1}(x^{-1})^{-1})=x1=x.$$